# SharePoint 2013 responsive branding

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, branding

I want to deliver SharePoint 2013 responsive site that affects all site collections in a greenfield site.

I've seen resources that mention editing the master page and adding a css file but this would be needed for every site collection?

Is there a way to deploy a solution that affects all site collections or is the preferred way to create a wsp of master and css file and activate on every site collection as and when created ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would customize a template (pick one as per your requirement) and then deploy the template in the farm.

Then whenever I create a new site collection, I will use that custom template.

But it is upto your environment.

Comment: Do you mean site collection level templates ?

Comment: Yes, pick one template. this is an idea, i am not developer but this is what we did in one of my previous project.

Answer (score 0):

Device channels might be your loyal friend.

With this tool, you could assign css files to a specified type of device.

Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862343.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of composed looks you can try with design manager and develop your own look and feel. However if you are not familiar with that,

Createa minimal master page either by copying the Seattle or by design manager HTML method

You can use SharePoint Drive connect method or SharePoint designer, No need to develop wsp, Drop all the files in site assets library and point to them in master page. Sharepoint 2013 gives more flexible to do

or

You can even create sandbox solution and upload the wsp to site collection from the site settings page.

Develop the CSS using media quires or use the any existing templates like bootstrap. However the sharepoint provides Resposive which is difficult to understand sharepoint way of developing responsive css

Answer (score 0):

For complete control create a customised Masterpage with page layouts. Use the bootstrap framework and edit your css to use media query breakpoints.

This is a custom masterpage, page layout solution i built (the video quality isn't great)

https://youtu.be/UuaLCjy882o